# Duda al Mostrar Registros de Usuario Logeado

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Buen día, tengo un problema al mostrar la informacion de cada usuario, en este hay unos formulario los cuales almacenan en una base de datos, el código es el siguiente:

**Login del Usuario:**

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'funcs/conexion.php';
include 'funcs/funcs.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){ //Si no ha iniciado sesión redirecciona a index.php
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

$sql = "SELECT id, nombre FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$idUsuario'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

?>

**Lista de Registros:**

```
            <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>No. Cotización</th>
                <th>Nombre o Razón Social</th>
                <th>Nombre del Representante de las Instalaciones</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Capacidad en KW</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            if($filter){
                $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cotizacion WHERE estado='$filter' ORDER BY codigo desc");
            }else{
                //$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cotizacion ORDER BY codigo desc");
                $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cotizacion WERE id = '$idUsuario' ORDER BY codigo desc");
            }
            if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0){
                echo '<tr><td colspan="8">No hay datos.</td></tr>';
            }else{

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                    echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td>C-UIIE-04-18-04-'.$row['codigo'].'</td>
                        <td><a href="profile_coti.php?nik='.$row['cotiz1'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> '.$row['cotiz1'].'</a></td>
                        <td>'.$row['cotiz2'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['cotiz3'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['cotiz4'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                    ';

                }
            }
            ?>
```

**Con este código guardo los registros del formulario a una base de datos:**

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['add'])){
            $codigo          = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["codigo"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres
            $cotiz1          = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["cotiz1"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
            $cotiz2          = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["cotiz2"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
            $cotiz3          = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["cotiz3"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
            $cotiz4          = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["cotiz4"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
            $cotiz5          = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["cotiz5"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
            $cotiz6          = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["cotiz6"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
            $cotiz7          = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["cotiz7"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
            $id          = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["id"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 

            $cek = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cotizacion WHERE codigo='$codigo'");
            if(mysqli_num_rows($cek) == 0){
                    $insert = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO cotizacion(codigo, cotiz1, cotiz2, cotiz3, cotiz4, cotiz5, cotiz6, cotiz7, id)
                                                        VALUES('$codigo', '$cotiz1', '$cotiz2', '$cotiz3', '$cotiz4', '$cotiz5', '$cotiz6', '$cotiz7', '$id')") or die(mysqli_error());
                    if($insert){
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Bien hecho! Tu solicitud fue enviada con éxito, te contactaremos en breve.</div>';
                    }else{
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Error. No se pudo guardar los datos !</div>';
                    }

            }else{
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Error. código exite!</div>';
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Base de Datos
[image: Esta es la estructura de la tabla del formulario:]

[image: Esta es la estructura de la tabla usuarios]

La idea es mostrar los registros que realice cada usuario en su sesión, pero la verdad nose como lograr este objetivo ya que apenas estoy empezando en esto, espero alguien me pueda apoyar.

Gracias y saludos!